# How to activate a javascript onclick button if it's inside a drop down HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a feature that's supposed to resize the font size inside a text area upon selecting a font size. It's working perfectly... but if I start putting the selection of font sizes in a drop down menu, it's no longer working.

Here's what the code looks like right now:

```js
        var documenttextsizer={

        prevcontrol: '', 
        existingclasses: '',

        setpageclass:function(control, newclass){
            if (this.prevcontrol!='')
                    this.css(this.prevcontrol, 'selectedtoggler', 'remove') 
            document.documentElement.className=this.existingclasses+' '+newclass
            this.css(control, 'selectedtoggler', 'add') 
            this.setCookie('pagesetting', newclass, 5) 
            this.prevcontrol=control
        },

        css:function(el, targetclass, action){
            var needle=new RegExp("(^|\\s+)"+targetclass+"($|\\s+)", "ig")
            if (action=="check")
                return needle.test(el.className)
            else if (action=="remove")
                el.className=el.className.replace(needle, "")
            else if (action=="add")
                el.className+=" "+targetclass
        },

        getCookie:function(Name){ 
            var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i"); 
            if (document.cookie.match(re)) 
                return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] 
            return null
        },

        setCookie:function(name, value, days){
            if (typeof days!="undefined"){ 
                var expireDate = new Date()
                var expstring=expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+days)
                document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; path=/; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()
            }
            else
                document.cookie = name+"="+value
        },

        setup:function(targetclass){
            this.existingclasses=document.documentElement.className
            var persistedsetting=this.getCookie('pagesetting')
            var alllinks=document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            for (var i=0; i<alllinks.length; i++){
                if (this.css(alllinks[i], targetclass, "check")){
                    if (alllinks[i].getAttribute("rel")==persistedsetting) 
                        this.setpageclass(alllinks[i], alllinks[i].getAttribute("rel")) 
                    alllinks[i].onclick=function(){
                        documenttextsizer.setpageclass(this, this.getAttribute("rel"))
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        }

    

        documenttextsizer.setup("texttoggler")
```

```css
.xsmallview textarea{
font-size: 11px;
}

.smallview textarea{
font-size: 13px;
}

.normalview{ 
}

.largeview textarea{
font-size: 21px;
}

.xlargeview textarea{
font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="40" rows="8"></textarea>
```

```
  <select>
    <option><a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="xsmallview">14px</a></option>
    <option><a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="smallview">15px</a></option>
    <option><a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="largeview">16px</a></option>
    <option><a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="xlargeview">18px</a></option>
  </select>
```

I'm sorry to ask such a question. But I've been working on this for some time now and still can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

`<option>` tags dont accept html, only valid contents are text and attributes of the tag itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

You will need to create a `value` of each option tag, e.g:

```
<select id="fontSizeToggle">
<option value="14">14px</option>
<option value="15">15px</option>
</select>
```

Then read the value of select box and perform the corresponding action